# Describing ireducible elements of $D[X]$ in terms of $D$ and the polynomial ring over its quotient field

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, field-theory, galois-theory

I need to describe the irreducible elements of $D[X]$, with $D$ being a UFD, in terms of irreducible elements of D and irreducible elements of $F[X]$, with $F$ being the quotient field of $D$.

I was thinking that I could use Gauss's Lemma where an irreducible element in $D[X]$ irreducible if and only if it is irreducible in $F[X]$ and primitive in $D[X]$. So, I can see my UFD $D$ as a GCD domain satisfying (ACCP). Then take an irreducible element in D[X] in the form:

$p(x)=a_0+a_1x+...+a_nx^n$

find the GCD of ${a_0, \dots ,a_n}$, say $b$, and see $p(x)$ in the form:

$p(x)=b(a'_0+a'_1x+ \dots +a'_nx^n)$

where $(a'_0+a'_1x+ \dots +a'_nx^n)$ would be an irreducible element in $F[X]$? By Gauss's Lemma?

Have I got the right idea or am I completely lost? Sorry, this topic confuses me a lot. Thank you for any help.

Comment: This is indeed the right idea. Looking at the proof for $\mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{Q}$ will show you that we use nothing special besides the properties you mentioned.